# jQuery slider with background color range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've looked at many questions that are similar to mine but I didn't see my question specifically. What I'm trying to do is have a slider with a single handle but in the background the slider range has a target range indicated with green (or any other color). Ideally you could also have some bleed color outside the target which indicated a border case. I'm imagining it too look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1) Create an image and put it as the background of the slider.

2) Nest some divs inside the slider body and style it however you like. http://jsfiddle.net/6Whzm/1/

Comment: Ok, this is very helpful. In my case I would have a number of "markers" where each marker is represented by a slider and for each type the range (min,max), stepping-frequency, and the suggested range will be data driven. Your example is making placements on a percentage basis than the underlying number system. Do I need to reverse-engineer this into a percentage to make it work?

Comment: This may be better addressed as a separate question but is it possible to have the values show up as tick markers (like my illustration above), ideally with a numeric key for min and max (and maybe median)

Comment: @ken slider handles themselves are positioned using percentages so I would recommend doing the same for most related stylings. Showing tick markers is not really a part of the slider itself; just have a separate image below the slider with the relevant sizing and set the slider `step` option.